# Notification question

Tags: android, notifications

I want to show a notification when a call is active.
I have done the first easy part.  Notification starts when my call intent starts.
Now to the tricky part,   how can I tell my Notification that the call has ended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) on the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html).

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

PhoneStateListener listener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
            // hangup    
        }
    } 
};

tm.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

To unregister your PhoneStateListener:

```
tm.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
```

Comment: which state is the "hang up state" .  Can only see STATE_RINGING, STATE_OFFHOOK, STATE_IDLE

Comment: You start listening for the STATE_IDLE after a call has been initiated that will indicate that the call has ended